# Limit $\lim_{n\to \infty} n^2\int _0^1\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, lebesgue-measure

$\lim_{n\to \infty} n^2\int _0^1\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^n}=?.$

My attempt: I want to use Lebesgue Dominated convergence theorem to solve this, Because I see that for $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n^2}{(1+x^2)^n}$ is zero on $
(0,1]$ so I split the integral into $[0,\epsilon]$ and $[\epsilon,1]$ and by Lebesgue Dominated convergence theorem the integral on $[\epsilon,1]$ is $0$ and since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary can I conclude the required limit to be $0.$

Comment: what about the integral on $[0,\epsilon]$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\int_0^{\frac 1 {\sqrt n}} \frac {n^{2}} {(1+x^{2})^{n}}dx \geq \int_0^{\frac 1 {\sqrt n}} \frac {n^{2}} {(1+\frac 1 n)^{n}}dx \to \infty$.

Comment: thanks for your answer Sir, I just want to ask what made you think of this method to approach the problem?

Comment: @user345777 The factor $n^{2}$ looked to big for this to converge to a finite limit since $(1+x^{2})^{n}$ is close to $1$ for $x$ near $0$, so I decided to consider the integral in some interval around $0$.

Comment: Sir suppose if I change the factor $n^2$ by $n^\alpha$,  $\alpha> 0$ then does the limit still go to infinity by the same method

Comment: @user345777 Not sure. I have to think about it a bit.

Comment: @user345777 Clearly it will tend to $0$ for $\alpha< 1/2$. The most interesting case is $\alpha=1/2$.

Comment: @user345777 For $\alpha =\frac 1 2$ the limit is $\int_0^{\infty} \frac {e^{-y}} {\sqrt {2y}} dy$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Are you sure? I would suggest it is $\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-y}}{2\sqrt{y}}dy=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}$.

Comment: @user You are right. I had made a small mistake in my calculation.

Answer (score 2):

Late answer since it is a duplicate somewhere else.

Note that for $n>1$

$$n^2\int_0^1\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^n}dx > n^2\int_0^1\frac{x}{(1+x^2)^n}dx$$ $$= \frac{n^2}{2} \int_0^1 \frac{d(1+x^2)}{(1+x^2)^n}$$
$$= \frac{n^2}{2(n-1)}\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\right)$$
$$> \frac{n}{4}$$